# Is it possible to make a type of generic array's property values

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I am trying to restrict values for a property (or react props in my case) based on what values are given in another property.

I have my Option interface

```
interface Option {
  value: string;
  label: string;
}
```

I then have my SelectInputProps interface

```
interface SelectInputProps<T extends Option> {
  options: T[];
  defaultValue: string;
}
```

What I want is to the make defaultValue only accept any string present in options values.

```
interface SelectInputProps<T extends Option> {
  options: T[];
  defaultValue: ThisShouldOnlyAcceptStringsInOptionsValues;
}
```

I have read this article which is close to my use case, [here](https://steveholgado.com/typescript-types-from-arrays/), but it gets types from already defined arrays. I do not know what values will be passed, hence the generic.

I did try

```
interface SelectInputProps<T extends Option> {
  options: T[];
  defaultValue: Array<T>[number]['value'];
}
```

but this only restricts it to any string, which is no different from the first snippet.

I may be going in the complete wrong direction here and there may be a simpler way, all help appreciated.

**Edit**

Usage in React component:

```
const SelectInput = <T extends Option>({
  options,
  defaultValue,
}: SelectInputProps<T>) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(defaultValue);
  const [isSelecting, setIsSelecting] = React.useState(false);

  const optionElements = options.map((option) => (
    <option value={option.value} key={option.value}>
      {option.label}
    </option>
  ));

  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
        <p>{options.find((op) => op.value === value)?.label}</p>
        <MdExpandMore size={'1.5rem'} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: you can just write `T['value']`. But I guess you are not showing us the full picture here? Where are you using this type?

Comment: @TobiasS. usage has been added

Comment: @TobiasS. I have tried just T['value'] but that results in the type 'string'. Any string can be passed, it's not restricted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type inference is a tricky subject in TypeScript. The issue here is not only the generic type itself but the function declaration too. When you pass an array like `[{value: "abc", label: "abc"}]` to a function, TypeScript has to decide how this array literal will be interpreted.

TypeScript will default widen types like this by default. So it infers the array literal

```
[{value: "abc", label: "abc"}]
```

as

```
{ value: string, label: string }[]
```

While this technically is a perfectly valid description of the passed array literal, we lose a lot of type information. It is not possible for us to get the type of `value` since it just a `string` now.

Luckily for us, there are certain tricks to force TypeScript to infer types as narrow as we need them to be.

---

Let's start with the interfaces.

```
interface Option<V extends string> {
  value: V;
  label: string;
}

interface SelectInputProps<T extends Option<V>[], V extends string> {
  options: T;
  defaultValue: T[number]["value"];
}
```

We will introduce a new generic type `V` which will hold information about the string literal type for `value`.

When we declare the function, we also have to add `V`.

```
const SelectInput = <T extends Option<V>[], V extends string>({
  options,
  defaultValue,
}: SelectInputProps<T, V>) => {
  /* ... */
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/FASwtgDg9gTgLgAgEoFMCGBjRAzGUwIBEM6WhwoAdnCjNpiggPIRwhSUA8AagigB41KAEwDOCUXBghKAcwB8CAN7AECAG5oANgFcUALgTcA3KoRa0AIxRbDk6XNMBfCjJp0GCAMo2UWAJKUEDpwAAp4EKKcACp8gigi4ixsHDzyANoAugA0RnFCYhJSMgrKZlCs7JSihtGmasIo9DpacNzaerXplDpg1jCZ6YSauiiEmc4UwBgckt6+AUEhCAC8CDH5CYXJVWlZubwCBeL2JfIAFCpqFSnV2WaNza3to-dOhj5afnCBwWERUWiB3kAEpVoorggZtVEOkRnpcqIUG0OihMqtkKQ4AA6HRIrxwNA0c6PNAtFGjEH1KGzWEgUSfb4lRHI-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)

---

Here some test cases:

```
function test(){
  return (<div>
    <SelectInput options={
        [{value: "a", label: "a"}, {value: "b", label: "b"}]
      } defaultValue="wrong"></SelectInput> // Error: Type '"wrong"' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b"'
    <SelectInput options={
        [{value: "a", label: "a"}, {value: "b", label: "b"}]
      } defaultValue="a"></SelectInput>
  </div>)
}
```

Comment: Great, am I right in assuming this method leverages the rules in this PR: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676 In which extending the type makes in non-widening?

Comment: Hmm I don't know if this issue affects what I am doing here. There is this really great blog post which explains type narrowing for function arguments in detail https://catchts.com/infer-arguments